# jQuery - How to debug a jQuery Table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Good day!

I have tables that are working on my 3 previous php files. The one file is exactly the same function/process but different modal id.

include_once 'modal\offense.php'; & include_once 'modal\claim.php';

the problem is:
I copy the entirely code of the offense.php and pasteit to claim.php
and I change the modal id for claim.php: offenseModal to claimModal and some codes like attribute for all input tag.

When I call the claimModal the tables are not working.

here's the working screenshot for the offense.php

[image: offense]

and here's for claim.php

[image: claim]

as you can see the pagination and search textbox are gone.

and also the process when clicking the table all the data in the table will copy to the textbox but it's not working because of the table are not load corretly.

these are the codes for jQuery tables:

for offense table

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
$('#offenseTable').dataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[5, -1], [5,"All"]]
} );

var table = $('#offenseTable').DataTable();
$('#offenseTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        document.getElementById("offStudID").value = data[1];
        document.getElementById("offStudLN").value = data[2];
        document.getElementById("offStudFN").value = data[3];
        document.getElementById("offStudMN").value = data[4];
        document.getElementById("offSuffix").value = data[5];
        document.getElementById("offStudCourse").value = data[6];
        document.getElementById("offStudLevel").value = data[7];
        // alert( 'You clicked on '+data[3]+'\'s row' );
    } );
```

});

and for claim table

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
$('#claimTable').dataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[5, -1], [5,"All"]]
} );

var table = $('#claimTable').DataTable();
$('#claimTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        document.getElementById("claimStudID").value = data[1];
        document.getElementById("claimStudLN").value = data[2];
        document.getElementById("claimStudFN").value = data[3];
        document.getElementById("claimStudMN").value = data[4];
        document.getElementById("claimSuffix").value = data[5];
        document.getElementById("claimStudCourse").value = data[6];
        document.getElementById("claimStudLevel").value = data[7];
        // alert( 'You clicked on '+data[3]+'\'s row' );
    } );
```

});

Note: the HTML and PHP codes are the same. Only their id are not same.

code for the current PHP where the modal will called:

```
include_once 'modal\createUser.php';
include_once 'modal\maintenance.php';
include_once 'modal\logHistory.php';
include_once 'modal\siteHistory.php';
include_once 'modal\offense.php';
include_once 'modal\claim.php';
```

and for the script:

```
<!-- JQUERY SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- METISMENU SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
<!-- DATA TABLE SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/table.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

These are the div id for the offense table together with modal id

modal ID:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="offenseModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

offense table:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="offenseTable">
```

for the claim table

modal ID:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="claimModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

claim table:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="claimTable">
```

**UPDATE 2**

I manage to get to work but it's weird. When this code is outside the table.js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#viewClaimTable').dataTable( {
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
        } );
    });
</script>
```

it's working. I want to put that code inside table.js so that I can call that id anywhere on the page.

here's the code inside table.js

```js
// Log History Table
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#logHistoryTable').dataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    } );
});
// Site History Table
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#siteHistoryTable').dataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    } );
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#viewStudOffenseTable').dataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    } );
});

$(document).ready(function () {            
    $('#offenseTable').dataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[5, -1], [5,"All"]]
    } );

    var table = $('#offenseTable').DataTable();
    $('#offenseTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var data = table.row( this ).data();
            document.getElementById("offStudID").value = data[1];
            document.getElementById("offStudLN").value = data[2];
            document.getElementById("offStudFN").value = data[3];
            document.getElementById("offStudMN").value = data[4];
            document.getElementById("offSuffix").value = data[5];
            document.getElementById("offStudCourse").value = data[6];
            document.getElementById("offStudLevel").value = data[7];
            // alert( 'You clicked on '+data[3]+'\'s row' );
        } );
});

$(document).ready(function () {            
    $('#claimTable').dataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[5, -1], [5,"All"]]
    } );

    var table = $('#claimTable').DataTable();
    $('#claimTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var data = table.row( this ).data();
            document.getElementById("claimStudID").value = data[1];
            document.getElementById("claimStudLN").value = data[2];
            document.getElementById("claimStudFN").value = data[3];
            document.getElementById("claimStudMN").value = data[4];
            document.getElementById("claimSuffix").value = data[5];
            document.getElementById("claimStudCourse").value = data[6];
            document.getElementById("claimStudLevel").value = data[7];
            // alert( 'You clicked on '+data[3]+'\'s row' );
        } );
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#viewClaimTable').dataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    } );
});
```

Comment: Where's your HTML for where you build the tables? My guess would be that you're using the same div id for both tables.

Comment: @jonmrich added an update. Thanks

Comment: Debug using the chrome developer tools this link may help [ChromeDeveloperTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) and please don't copy past code,make it reusable

Comment: but can you explain on my other code that uses modal with tables? I can't figure it out what is not working.

Comment: please check my new update: Update 2